# Rendering pdf in handlebars-express in the server

Tags: pdf, server, handlebars.js, template-engine

I'm having difficulty getting a pdf file to render correctly. I have attempted the three separate attempts below, they **are not** being used together. I've attempted to use the first two (with embed, and the object with a nested iframe, both in the Handlebars-express framework). And when I couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong, I tried to render on the client side using the app.js script and throwing an embed on the client. The paths are correct. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div>
  <embed width="100%" height="100%" src="/pdf/file1.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</div>

<object data="/pdf/file1.pdf" type="img" width="100%" height="100%">
  <iframe src="/pdf/file1.pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="border: none;">
   It looks like the browser you are using does not support PDFs. However, you can still download my resume to view it: <a href="/pdf/file1.pdf">Download PDF</a>
  </iframe>
</object> 

<script src="src/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The file was corrupt. After attempting every exhaustible answer, that was the culprit. If you are experiencing similar issues, first check the sanitation of the file in question.